# Instance "description" - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, instance

If I have an instance that looks like this:

```js
/**
 * @param prefix?: string
 */
export interface ClientConfig {
  prefix?: string;
}
```

How can I access the `@param prefix?: string` using code?

Comment: It is an interface not a instance (you cannot instantiate an interface). An interface is sort of a "contract". If you want to want to implement the ClientConfig, you need to include the prefix  variable. The @param is just an comment. You cannot access it.

Comment: why do you use jsDocs type annotations if you've already described types with typescript? And why do you want to access comments?

Answer (score 0):

`ClientConfig` is an interface, not an instance.

You can use it in a TypeScript project like you would use a type:

```
const config: ClientConfig = {
  prefix: 'my-prefix'
};
```

To access the `prefix` property, you can do `config.prefix` (note that `prefix` is not required since there's a `?` on the field).

Comment: Oh sorry! I should've made this a bit clearer, I don't want to get the value exactly. But rather the literal text "@param prefix?: string"

Comment: It's a JSDoc annotation, I don't think you can. To access the type of the `prefix` property, you can do `ClientConfig['prefix']` though

Comment: Mind accepting the answer/upvoting if it's solved it for you?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access this data, as it is JSDoc annotation as said by Hugo